# Making Pointer that reads string while over it - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, string, xcode, swiftui, attributedstring

I want to make the following behavior possible in SwiftUI but i dont know how:

Imagine having a Text that contains a string (or attributed string), also you have a pointer that can be hovered over the letters of the string like a mouse icon (or any icon), as the pointer goes on a letter, that letter gets highlighted (i.e colors differently).

What i dont want:
I dont want you to use different Texts and add them up using an HStack and Foreach, i want it to be all together, since i want it work for all languages and the method mentioned works for language that have unconnected letters only.

is it possible?

Comment: "as the pointer goes on a letter" How does it do this? Is the pointer controlled by the user (by dragging?), or something else?

Comment: dragging would do, or having a fixed pointer above the text, and when you scroll the text and that pointer hits a letter, it gets highlighted?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i believe it is quite clear, what makes it unclear if u can tell me to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring), [NSTextAttachment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachment) can achieve your needs.

I encapsulate it in `HighlightWithCursorLabel`:

```
struct HighlightWithCursorLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var originText: String
    var color: UIColor
    @Binding var highlightIndex: Int
    
    var configuration = { (view: UILabel) in }
                
    init(originText: String, color: UIColor, highlightIndex: Binding<Int>, configuration: @escaping (UILabel) -> () = { _ in }) {
        self.originText = originText
        self.color = color
        self._highlightIndex = highlightIndex
        self.configuration = configuration
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = originText
        label.textColor = UIColor(Colors.subText)
        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        configuration(uiView)
        
        if highlightIndex > originText.count { return }
        
        let attributString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originText)
        
        let nsRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: highlightIndex)
        let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
        attributString.addAttributes(attribute, range: nsRange)

        let attachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "cursorarrow")!.withTintColor(color)) // replace it to any UIImage
        let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

        attributString.insert(attachmentString, at: highlightIndex)
        uiView.attributedText = attributString
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
struct HighlightSampleView: View {
    @State private var highlightIndex: Int = 0
    private var text = "Hello World~~~~~"
    
    var body: some View {
        HighlightWithCursorLabel(originText: text, color: UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0), highlightIndex: $highlightIndex)
            .onAppear {
                highlightText()
            }
    }
    
    // To show the highlight effect, replace it when you want to update index
    private func highlightText() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            highlightIndex += 1
            
            if highlightIndex > text.count {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HighlightSampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HighlightSampleView()
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the issue is the cursor is not over the text as a separate entity but embedded in the attributed string, which creates this pushing of text to left effect that i do not desire. can you make it hover over without interfering with the text except highlighting?

Comment: If you just want to allow users to hover over text and highlight it, you can consider using the native `UITextView` which have select/highlight text feature. Then you can add a `UIImageView` and continuously update its position based on user clicks and drags. If you want to customize the highlighting color of text further, You can try using `NSAttributedString`, [convert(_:from:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622424-convert) and [glyphIndex(for:in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403112-glyphindex).